# Use tensorflow TPU strategy; get UnavailableError

Tags: python, tensorflow, google-colaboratory

**Methods I tried:**

- same steps 1-3, used CPU, model works but very slow
- switch to TPU, got error
- same steps 1-3, switch to GPU, model works a bit faster than CPU

I tried to train my model with Tensorflow 8 core TPU at colab, but it kept to return errors.

**Steps to save data and build model:**

1. save my data in `pandas.DataFrame`
2. create `ImageDataGenerator` and then use `flow_from_dataframe` to retrieve batch of data
3. build a model **Inception V3 + one multi-output layer**
4. under the `TPUStrategy.scope()`, create my model and compile it.
5. fit my data into the model, get **error**

```
Epoch 1/10

---------------------------------------------------------------------------

UnavailableError                          Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-22-928195762eae> in <module>()
      2           steps_per_epoch=STEP_SIZE_TRAIN,
      3           epochs=10,
----> 4           verbose=1,
      5 )

13 frames

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/six.py in raise_from(value, from_value)

UnavailableError: 9 root error(s) found.
  (0) Unavailable: {{function_node __inference_train_function_104631}} failed to connect to all addresses
Additional GRPC error information from remote target /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0:
:{"created":"@1617112726.695916504","description":"Failed to pick subchannel","file":"third_party/grpc/src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/client_channel.cc","file_line":4143,"referenced_errors":[{"created":"@1617112726.695913862","description":"failed to connect to all addresses","file":"third_party/grpc/src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/lb_policy/pick_first/pick_first.cc","file_line":398,"grpc_status":14}]}
     [[{{node MultiDeviceIteratorGetNextFromShard}}]]
     [[RemoteCall]]
     [[IteratorGetNextAsOptional]]
     [[Pad_10/paddings/_234]]
  (1) Unavailable: {{function_node __inference_train_function_104631}} failed to connect to all addresses
Additional GRPC error information from remote target /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0:
:{"created":"@1617112726.695916504","description":"Failed to pick subchannel","file":"third_party/grpc/src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/client_channel.cc","file_line":4143,"referenced_errors":[{"created":"@1617112726.695913862","description":"failed to connect to all addresses","file":"third_party/grpc/src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/lb_policy/pick_first/pick_first.cc","file_line":398,"grpc_status":14}]}
     [[{{node MultiDeviceIteratorGetNextFromShard}}]]
     [[RemoteCall]]
     [[IteratorGetNextAsOptional]]
     [[ConstantFoldingCtrl/cond_11/switch_pred/_107_0/_151]]
  (2) Unavailable: {{function_node __inference_train_function_104631}} failed to connect to all addresses
Additional GRPC error information from remote target /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0:
:{"created":"@1617112726.695916504","description":"Failed to pick subchannel","file":"third_party/grpc/src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/client_channel.cc","file_line":4143,"referenced_errors":[{"created":"@1617112726.695913862","description":"failed to connect to all addresses","file":"third_party/grpc/src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/lb_policy/pick_first/pick_first.cc","file_line":398,"grpc_status":14}]}
     [[{{node MultiDeviceIteratorGetNextFromShard}}]]
     [[RemoteCall]]
     [[IteratorGetNextAsOptional]]
     [[cluster_train_function/_execute_7_0/_1951]]
  (3) Unavailable: {{function_node __inference_train_function_104631}} failed to connect to all addresses
Additional GRPC error information from remote target /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0:
:{"created":"@1617112726.695916504","description":"Failed to pick subchannel","file":"third_party/grpc/src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/client_channel.cc","file_line":4143,"referenced_errors":[{"created":"@1617112726.695913862","description":"failed to connect to all addresses","file":"third_party/grpc/src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/lb_policy/pick_first/pick_first.cc","file_line":398,"grpc_status":14}]}
     [[{{node MultiDeviceIteratorGetNextFromShard}}]]
     [[RemoteCall]]
     [[IteratorGetNextAsOptional]]
     [[strided_slice_73/_1302]]
  (4) U ... [truncated]
```

Comment: Are you using `tf.data.Dataset.from_generator`?

Comment: @M.Innat It's ImageDataGenerator. So I suppose it a type of `tf.data.Dataset`.

Comment: Check [this](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/38762#issuecomment-787600368).